# Creating multi background colors <tr> with CSS

Tags: php, css

I'm working on a table for which I need more than just two background color for the "tr". What I'm using right now is :

```
.forum_table tr:nth-child(odd) { 
background-color:#f6f6f6; 
}

.forum_table  tr:nth-child(even) { 
background-color:#ffffff; 
}
```

But I need up to 5 different background colors for the same table. Is there any way to do that with CSS or do I need to do that with PHP which I'm not very good in?

Comment: Add a class to your `<tr>` elements for the colours that you need, and style that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzuDk/)

```
table tr:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
    background: #f00;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(5n+2) {
    background: #0f0;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
    background: #5d54fd;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(5n+4) {
    background: #564844;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(5n+5) {
    background: #00f;
}
```

Explanation: using `(int)n` will select every `+ nth tr` element, this way you can select `n` number of color combinations, and not just odd and even

Comment: nth-of-type(2n) will conflict with nth-of-type(4n) every fourth row, and nth-of-type(3n) every sixth row. This won't be very pretty.

Answer (score 2):

`:nth-child(kn)` [where `k`is an integer number] selector is your hero:

```
.forum_table  tr:nth-child(n){ ... }
.forum_table  tr:nth-child(2n){ ... }
.forum_table  tr:nth-child(3n){ ... }
...
.forum_table  tr:nth-child(kn){ ... }
```

Comment: Aaaa same... I was just creating a fiddle though :)

Comment: There's not really much point specifying a rule for `tr:nth-child(n)`, since it's precisely equivalent to `tr`.